# In a JSP page can you use reflection to display all of a Model object's particular properties?

Tags: java, jsp, reflection, spring-mvc, jstl

In a JSP page can you use reflection to display all of a Model object's particular properties?

Supposing I have three Model types (`Foo`, `Goo`, `Hoo`) and - in a single JSP/JSTL page - I want to loop over a List of objects containing, at any moment, one of these three types.

Is there a way to use reflection to determine the fields in the Model on the JSP page without having to include a `CHOOSE/WHEN/OTHERWISE` block based on the actual type of the Model object?

I have an admin page where I want to provide a dropdown where the admin can choose which Model object they want to inspect.

The form would get submitted to a request handler where a particular subset of Model objects are looked up and returned to the admin page to be displayed & paginated.

### Admin.jsp

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${models}" var="model" varStatus="status">        
    <tr>
        <!-- Probably need an inner loop here -->
        <td><!-- Display model instance properties using reflection --></td>
        <!-- End of inner loop -->
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

### Foo

```
@Repository
public class Foo{
    private int id;
    private boolean isFooIsh;
    // other properties . . . 
}
```

### Goo

```
@Repository
public class Goo{
    private int id;
    private boolean isGooIsh;
    // other properties . . . 
}
```

### Hoo

```
@Repository
public class Hoo{
    private int id;
    private boolean isHooIsh;
    // other properties . . . 
}
```

Comment: Very similar question was removed because it was offensive. Your name is also very similar to the name of the person who asked that question...

Answer (score 3):

Of course you *can*. Whether you *should* is up for debate. By virtue of scriptlets and/or custom tags, you can do pretty much any Java code you want in a JSP.

Comment: Never, ever put Java scriptlets on JSP pages.  They can't be unit tested, designers will muck them up, etc.